Adding (increment) values to a record in Laravel or creating a new row
I want to say that if there is a row in the "ListingPoints" model where "ListingPoints" is equal to 1 and "review_cat_id" is equal to 1, then the value of "review_count" is equal to "\Auth::user()->rate". And increase the value of "sum_star" by 10, for example.
If there is no such record, create a record with the same values, i.e. the following values
ListingPoints => 1
review_cat_id => 1
review_count => \Auth::user()->rate
sum_star => 10

I am going to use updateOrCreate. But I don't know how to set the "review_count" and "sum_star" values.

This is the code I wrote myself:
ListingPoints::query()->updateOrCreate(
                ['listing_id' => $request->listing_id, 'review_cat_id' => $key],
                [
                    'review_count' => \Auth::user()->rate,
                    'sum_star' => 10,
                ]
            );

But it seems to me that this code will insert the values I gave it instead of adding to the previous value when the row being searched for exists. please advise me
